# Why doesn't this sequence have any pointwise subsequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove that the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = \sin(n x)$ have no pointwise convergent subsequence

I am confused. If I let $x = 1$, then we get $f_n(1) = \sin(n)$. By Bolzano Weistress, we have a convergent subsequence no?

Answer (score 5):

A pointwise convergent subsequence would be a (sub)sequence of functions $f_i(x)$ such that $\lim_{i\to \infty} f_i(x)$ exists, for all $x$.

Comment: You wrote $\lim_{i \to \infty} f_i(x)$; isn't that just regular pointwise convergence?

Comment: Correct.  It's not the whole sequence $f_n(x)$ that converges pointwise, but a subsequence; i.e. choosing some functions but not others.

Comment: Right, and I chose $f_i(1)$, which shows there is a subsequence

Comment: You need convergence of some functions, for all $x$.  What you did was the convergence of some functions, for one $x$.